# Django, creating a view with a link

Tags: django, view

i want to do a simple thing in django, ok, i have a view where i save all my data in a database, but that data is generated with a code, and that code its in a link, for example

`127.0.0.1:8080/link/?code=ef713asd559q`

i have this variable "url" that generate the url(mentioned before) with the code, i want to create a view where when you press a button and will go to the "url", then take that code and pass it as a parameter to the first view where i fill the database... if you guys dont understand please tell me, my english is not so good, so for me its a little hard to explain this, please dont be rough on me, some people in this comunity always answers me badly, and makes me feel bad... lol

thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with Django forms ? If not definitely read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/

Comment: @shuttle87 He wants submit button to work but he never mentioned form before .....

Comment: I suspect the solution to this problem is fairly straightforward I just am not sure exaclty what's being asked... A clarifying edit to the question would be good here.

Comment: im using The instagram api, and that url is from the authentification ( url = unaunthenticated_api.get_authorize_url(scope=["likes","comments"]), i need that button to "call" the url and then take The code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the *code* then pass into *url* like

```
url(r'^link/?code=(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'save_link', name='save_link'),
```

then in your view

```
def save_link(request, id):
    pprint.pprint(id) # To check weather id's here or not!
    return HttpResponse('id 's here )
```

Comment: im using The instagram api, and that url is from the authentification ( url = unaunthenticated_api.get_authorize_url(scope=["likes","comments"]), i need that button to "call" the url and then take The code!

Comment: I make The button, and it worked, now, i need to take The code and pass it to The view called fill_db, how i do that?

Comment: doesnt show an error, just nothing happens, the link opens and the code does not print

Comment: check that in terminal when the url execute